# In Apify, how do I log to the console from within a nested function?

Tags: apify

From the Apify example docs, I can see that if you use `console.log()` within `handlePageFunction`, it is logged directly to the terminal console. The same is true for the Apify utils `log`. For example:

```js
handlePageFunction: async ({ request, page }) => {
    console.log('This is logged to the terminal console');
    log.info('So is this.')
    ...
}
```

However when I am defining my own functions *inside* handlePageFunction this, I cannot get anything logged to the terminal console. I expect the console.log is going to the browser console, but in Apify the browser window appears and disappears quickly. (It's also possible to use apify-cli which wouldn't even show a browser at all.)

```js
handlePageFunction: async ({ request, page }) => {
  ...
  const myFunction = () => {
    console.log('This disappears into the ether.');
    log.info('This causes the script to fail with error, "log is not defined"');
  }
  myFunction();
}
```

How do I use the Apify utils.log from within a nested javascript function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the defined function inside a `page.evaluate` or any other function that is evaluated in the browser context the `console.log` gets outputted inside the browser console. If you want to have the browser logs displayed inside the Node.js this should work for simple logging. -

```
page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text));
```